# Javascript / Jquery If condition with percentage for style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, percentage

I need to do an `if` comparison for a custom arrow system for a jquery slider.
The thing is I use "%" to do so and this code doesn't seem to work with percentage:

```
$( "#galerie-right" ).click(function() {
    var fg = $('.foogallery').css('left');
    if( fg==''){
        $('.foogallery').css('left', '-101%');
    } else if( fg=='-101%'){
        $('.foogallery').css('left', '-202%');
    }
});
```

I know `css()` apparently only take computed results, when the line:

```
$('.foogallery').css('left', '-101%');
```

is called, the html element have `style="left:-101%"` applied. Is there a way to maybe take this value somehow ?

Thanks,

**P.S**: There is only one item with the class `foogallery` selected

Comment: I'd rather recommend to add additional classes like `state1` and `state2` and then use jquery's `addClass` and `hasClass` functions.

Comment: aren't you getting the taking the value when you are doing `var fg = $('.foogallery').css('left');`

Comment: Sunil Lama, Well, I'm getting a pixel value with px at the end '0px' for exemple

Comment: Bragam Dev, this solution works like a charm, i'm posting the answer right away

Comment: @Gawet See my answer it's a functioning slider with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. This allows you to have any css in the classes and keeps your js independent of the css values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $('.foogallery').toggleClass("state1 state2");
  })
})
```

```css
.foogallery {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.foogallery.state1::before{
  content:'state1'
}
.foogallery.state2::before{
  content:'state2'
}
.foogallery.state1{
  background:#ccc;
}
.foogallery.state2{
  background:#fcc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foogallery state1"></div>
<button id="btn">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but it doesn't quite works with what I had in mind considering there's a left and a right arrow. Thanks anyway, it will definitly be useful for other projects !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Braham Dev, I found the solution.
Just store the css modifications in classes and adding/removing them when needed.
This is what my code looks like now:

```
$( "#galerie-right" ).click(function() {
           if($('.foogallery').hasClass('galerie-left202')==true){
               $('.foogallery').removeClass('galerie-left202');

           }else if($('.foogallery').hasClass('galerie-left101')==true){
                $('.foogallery').addClass('galerie-left202');
                $('.foogallery').removeClass('galerie-left101');

            }else{
                $('.foogallery').addClass('galerie-left101');
             }
       });
```

The CSS:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
div#galerie-photo div.foogallery.galerie-left101{left:-101%;}
div#galerie-photo div.foogallery.galerie-left202{left:-202%;}
```